# Disabling a particular row in a datatable IceFace

Tags: javascript, spring, jsf, icefaces

I have a screen in which certain data are displayed. I am using datatable option to display the data and rowselector to select the row.
If I select any row some option will pop up through which user can manipulate the data(like edit and delete), but i want some data to be non editable.

I have a screen in which i am showing data on month basis, like if current month is August then my page will show previous two months data and the next 10 months data.

Now i want current months and previous two months data to be non editable or disable while selection the row through rowselector. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nGgJv.png)

Below is the my View page  and rowselector function:

```
 <i:dataTable id="ConfigurationOne"
            headerClass="dataTableCommonHeader"
        headerClasses="table_header"
        columnClasses="stringColumn, stringColumn w80"
        rowClasses="level2ColorStyle, level1ColorStyle"
        value="#{configOneBean.monthsDateList}" var="row" cellpadding="0"
        cellspacing="1" columnWidths="50px,100px" rows="25"
        width="40%"
        onrowmouseover="this.style.cursor='default';this.style.backgroundColor='#F1F1F1'‌​;" 
        onrowmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='#{a4jSkin.tableBackgroundColor}'"
        >

        <i:column>
            <i:rowSelector value="#{row.selected}" 
                selectionListener="#{configOneBean.rowSelectMonthsListener}" />
            <f:facet name="header">
                <i:outputText value="#{resApp['config.type.code']}" />
            </f:facet>
            <i:panelGroup style="width:200px;overflow:hidden;">
                <i:outputText value="#{row.NRPV_NRPA_CODE}" />
            </i:panelGroup>
        </i:column>

        <i:column>

            <f:facet name="header">
                <i:outputText value="#{resApp['config.type.name']}" />
            </f:facet>
            <i:panelGroup style="width:200px;overflow:hidden;">
                <i:outputText value="#{row.NRPV_CREATED_BY}" />
            </i:panelGroup>
        </i:column>



    </i:dataTable>
```

---

```
public void rowSelectMonthsListener(RowSelectorEvent event) {
    int selectRow = event.getRow();
    initActionMap();
    if (event.isSelected()) {

        this.monthsDate = monthsDateList.get(selectRow);
        getAllMonthsAndDate();
        actionMap.put(WorkMode.EDIT_GROUP, true);

    } else {

        this.monthsDate = null;
        workMode = WorkMode.EMPTY;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `rowSelector` component does have a `rendered` attribute. If you bind it to a method to determine if the row can be clicked, this should do the trick. Not that I did not try this attribute in my code, but it *should* work if not bugged.

Comment: Hi **Wis** thanks for your reply....could you please elaborate little more, or any sample code would be a great help :)

Comment: I was proposing something like this : `<i:rowSelector value="#{row.selected}" selectionListener="#{configOneBean.rowSelectMonthsListener}" rendered="configOneBean.isSelectable(row)" />` and in your managed bean you should have a `public boolean isSelectable(Object obj)` which will test your variable `obj` against current date and determine if it should be selectable or not. Note that I do not know the type of your `obj` variable, maybe a `Date`, maybe a `Calendar` (my guess, but could be your own POJO).

Comment: Hi @Wis thanks for your reply.........i have tried to applied this logic but it will disable all the rows.....i am comparing data with the month name and if it find the months in the datatable then whole datatable will be disabled.